# How large are the pilot rest areas of the A380 and B747-8?

Tags: airbus-a380, boeing-747

How large are the pilot rest areas of an Airbus A380 and Boeing 747-8? What entertainment systems are found in them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pilot crew rest areas are not as large as flight attendant rest areas as they only provide space for 2 occupants. A380 and B747-800 pilot rest areas will have 2 sleeping berths, and most airlines will also have 2 comfortable seats equipped with the same in-flight entertainment as the passengers. This gives the resting pilot the choice to sleep in a bed, or relax in a comfortable chair. Sometimes, instead of a chair in the crew rest area, a regular Business class seat will be blocked for the pilot's use.

## Airbus A380

[Airbus A380 Pilot Crew Rest Area Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_RqT7JhM0k)

[image]

## Boeing 747

The B747-800 Pilot Rest area is behind the flight deck. This photo shows 2 bunks with blue bedding. Crew rest seats may or may not be available depending on the airlines own specifications or requirements.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can find some footage of [the A380 crew cabin here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=begDOPL3FIA). There appears to be about a dozen or so sleeping berths as well as a bathroom. You can find [some pictures here](https://www.ausbt.com.au/photos-the-airbus-a380-s-secret-hangout-zone-for-cabin-crew) and according to the article.

> The aviators also have their own entertainment screen when they’re
>   away from the cockpit, and unlike the tight-squeeze crew bunks,
>   there’s extra headspace if they’d prefer to sit in bed and read a good
>   book.

It does not note if the other berths have entertainment systems and its hard to tell in the video. I presume this is something the airline is free to order if they chose to.

---

Similar footage of the [747 crew cabin can be found here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocxw_pSVz50). The video states there are 8 berths. [This footage of a united 747 (1:30 in)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn1ymMOw_xE) shows some seats in the crew cabin along with the berths.