# Why does the A380 not have front windows on the top floor?

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus-a380, windows

The title says it all.

On the 747, the cockpit is in the upper level and in the lower there's equipment (radar, avionics, etc.)

But on the A380, the cockpit is in the lower floor and there's no equipment in the upper floor. So I think it could be technically possible to place some front windows in order to get a pilot-like view.

I guess that would reduce the aerodynamic efficience of the aircraft, but maybe it could be compensated by higher prices on those exclusive view seats?

Has any aircraft like that ever existed or designed?

Comment: No doubt someone would buy it and just close the window shade...

Comment: People would be freaking out all day watching aircraft on the same airway pass above and below only 1000 ft away, on precisely the same line thanks to GPS.  When they are some way out, it looks like they are coming right at you.

Comment: It would be a front row seat for a birdstrike.

Comment: @JohnK - Do commercial flights really get within 1000 ft of each other?

Comment: @BruceWayne Minimium vertical separation 1000 feet, I would think so.  I have seen planes cross the flight path of planes I have been on by not much more than that much, although the less parallel the paths are the less likely for a direct intercept.

Comment: @BruceWayne yes that's what RVSM,  Reduced Vertical Separation Minima, is about.  Vertical separation of opposing tracks was reduced from 2000 to 1000 ft in RVSM airspace.  Because GPS navigation places everybody exactly on the airway center line, there no random left/right distribution of tracks and opposing planes go straight over or straight under.

Comment: If passengers wanted a pilot's-eye view (or even views of what the pilot can't see with the naked eye) there are other options, involving cameras and display screens, that would provide a more interesting experience. Microphones and speakers could be added as well.

Comment: Certification requirements require that there be an exit path both in front of and behind a passenger seat, so any seats with a view cannot be occupied during takeoff and landing. (The Boeing 747 does not meet this safety requirement because it is grandfathered in.) This is why the areas in front of the forward stairwell are used as a lavatory or lounge.

Comment: @user71659 that could be an answer!

Comment: @JohnK Approaching each other at 500 m/s, I doubt many passengers would even realize that there's an airliner there before it's passed them. Travelling in the same direction, the relative speed would be comparatively small.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling If you have a clear view to the front, you can spot oncoming aircraft when they are a few miles out because you see a little grey splotch of the head-on contrail with a black speck in the middle, and it grows.  As it gets closer you can tell it's on a line that is above or below your level but initially the effect is quite striking the first time you see it.

Comment: @JohnK I don't doubt what you're saying, though I have no direct experience with that myself; however, how many average passengers would make the connection? (No pun intended there.)

Comment: Most people woudn't take much notice I'm sure but somebody would get excited sooner or later lol.

Comment: @user71659 - It is [the opposite](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.807), "If only one floor-level exit per side is prescribed, and the airplane does not have a tailcone or ventral emergency exit, the floor-level exits must be in the **rearward part** of the passenger compartment (...)". Even if we **presumed** that's the case, exemptions can be made if a suitable alternative can be designed, e.g., a forward slide that deploys after popping a large enough window panel.

Comment: @ymb1 Again, this is [well known](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/airbus-questions-boeings-certification-plan-for-new-widebody-747-8i-to-use-grandfathered-data-from-previous-jumbos-211624/) in the case of the 747, and why carriers have forward lounges in the A380. It is an interpretation by the FAA of the uniform exit requirement 25.807(c).

Comment: @user71659 - Uha! Thanks for the clarification. Reading that article, I'd say Boeing can counterargue Airbus' forward stairs don't constitute a *same deck* exit. I *think* as long as the evacuation tests pass, the authorities permit special cases.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[image]
([flightglobal.com](https://www.flightglobal.com/assets/getasset.aspx?ItemID=19916))

You'll need to zoom above 100% to read the legend, but up there it's not empty. There's the crew rest area (5), where the pilots rest for example, and it is easily accessible from the cockpit *(see below for how it interacts with the upper deck).*

There is also an electronics bay (29), and toilets (12).

Note that the cockpit is not on the main deck, it's between the main and upper decks, the mezzanine if you will.

Design-wise, the forehead is very sloped for aerodynamics, so to offer a forward-facing window view (if the area was empty), there will be an enormous unused legroom (for head clearance). The view also wouldn't allow seeing a big distance ahead and below, so it will be more like a skylight window, especially that airliners typically cruise with the [nose pointing above the horizon](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2726/14897). And with the area clear of walls and supporting structures, the plane will gain weight to strengthen the shell in that area.

For the secondary question see, '[Has any passenger airliner ever offered forward-facing windows?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54066/14897)'

[image]
([source](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/48572/14897))

Comment: During the assembly line construction project an engineer said to me that they can do much more with the needed extra weight (windows plus aluminium structures) in other places that it is not worth it giving the passengers a view to the same clouds they could see it of the side windows

Comment: The FCRC is not on the top floor on that diagram.  It is directly behind the cockpit.  On the top floor is 28, the "upper deck break-out zone".